# Add Bands of colours to a spiral shape plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, scatter-plot

I have the following code which creates and plots spiral on a **Matlab**. I want to have control of the colours and add three to four colours myself instead of matlab doing the colouring. How can i put colours myself and have control over the colours? Here is my code:

```
N = 1000;
r = linspace(0,1,N);
t = (3*pi/2)*(1+2*r);
x(1,:) = t.*cos(t);
x(2,:) = t.*sin(t);
x(3,:) = zeros(1,N);
ms = 50;
%cm = colormap;
%cm(64,:);

figure;
scatter3(x(1,:), x(2,:), x(3,:), ms, t, 'filled');
```

Any help please?

@jucestain, The colouring works, Thanks. I just have another question. If you add noise to the above code like this, the results become funny as shown

```
    N = 1000;
    r = linspace(0,1,N);
    t = (3*pi/2)*(1+2*r);
    x(1,:) = t.*cos(t);
    x(2,:) = t.*sin(t);
    x(3,:) = zeros(1,N);
    % Set colors:
    t(1:250) = 1;
    t(251:500) = 2;
    t(501:750) = 3;
    t(751:1000) = 4;
    ms = 50;
    figure;
    scatter3(x(1,:), x(2,:), x(3,:), ms, t, 'filled');

    %add noise
    x(1,:) = x(1,:) + 5*randn(1,N);
    x(2,:) = x(2,:) + 5*randn(1,N);
    x(3,:) = x(3,:) + 5*randn(1,N);
    figure;
    scatter3(x(1,:), x(2,:), x(3,:), ms, t, 'filled');
```

The results of this plot is very clumsy, i don't know why? Am i adding noise correctly or what? Is the plot right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The t vector you have controls the color. You can control it by altering the values in t. Here's an example:

```
N = 1000;
r = linspace(0,1,N);
t = (3*pi/2)*(1+2*r);
x(1,:) = t.*cos(t);
x(2,:) = t.*sin(t);
x(3,:) = zeros(1,N);
% Set colors:
t(1:250) = 1;
t(251:500) = 2;
t(501:750) = 3;
t(751:1000) = 4;
ms = 50;
figure;
scatter3(x(1,:), x(2,:), x(3,:), ms, t, 'filled');
```

Output:

[image]

The above depends on what kind of colormap you're using. You could also alternatively use this if you find it simpler:

```
N = 1000;
r = linspace(0,1,N);
t = (3*pi/2)*(1+2*r);
x(1,:) = t.*cos(t);
x(2,:) = t.*sin(t);
x(3,:) = zeros(1,N);
% Set colors:
ms = 50;
figure;
scatter3(x(1,1:250), x(2,1:250), x(3,1:250), ms, 'r', 'filled'); % red
hold on;
scatter3(x(1,251:500), x(2,251:500), x(3,251:500), ms, 'g', 'filled'); % green
scatter3(x(1,501:750), x(2,501:750), x(3,501:750), ms, 'b', 'filled'); % blue
scatter3(x(1,751:1000), x(2,751:1000), x(3,751:1000), ms, 'y', 'filled'); % yellow
hold off;
```

Output:

[image]

WRT to noise: You're adding way too much. rand ranges from 0 to 1, so you're adding noise ranging from 0 to 5, which is comparable to the values in the data. If you do this:

```
N = 1000;
r = linspace(0,1,N);
t = (3*pi/2)*(1+2*r);
x(1,:) = t.*cos(t);
x(2,:) = t.*sin(t);
x(3,:) = zeros(1,N);
% Set colors:
t(1:250) = 1;
t(251:500) = 2;
t(501:750) = 3;
t(751:1000) = 4;
ms = 50;
figure;
scatter3(x(1,:), x(2,:), x(3,:), ms, t, 'filled');

%add noise
x(1,:) = x(1,:) + .5*randn(1,N);
x(2,:) = x(2,:) + .5*randn(1,N);
x(3,:) = x(3,:) + .5*randn(1,N);
figure;
scatter3(x(1,:), x(2,:), x(3,:), ms, t, 'filled');
```

You obtain:

[image]

Which is pretty reasonable.

Comment: This colouring works, Thanks. I just have another question. If you add noise to the above code like this, the results become funny as shown

Comment: @user2179716 if the answer works you should accept it. Also, can you elaborate on adding noise?

Comment: I just want to add some noise by adding some random numbers using gaussian with mean 0 and variance of 5. as shown in my edited code.

Comment: Yes, with standard deviation less than 1, it is reasonable, but how about more than 1, sany 3, 4, 5 etc?

Comment: @user2179716 look at your range of values, they range from -10 to 10 in the x and y directions and even less in the x-direction -0.5 to 0.5. This has nothing to do with the `scatter3` function. Your signal to noise ratio is just too high.

Comment: @user2179716 That's a pretty subjective question. But yea, I'd say anything about 1 will probably give very poor results...

Comment: Thanks, you have answered my prevous question. I just want to ask you just one more question. How can i embedd it on a high dimensional data? I just want to try it out.

Comment: kindly help me with the embedding on high dimensions. I have accepted you previous answer, this is just a question i am asking your opinion on. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by embedding in higher dimensional data. Do you mean inserting this 3-d obtain in 4-d data? Try to make a stab at it; if you can't solve it then post it as another question and maybe others can help you.

Comment: Yes, that is what i mean. Instead of having the points in 3-d, we have them in higher dimension say 10 or even 100 dimensions. Any idea how this can go?

Comment: @user2179716 human beings cannot perceive things beyond the 3rd dimension. In order to display this you'd need to do something weird, like passing a 4d object through a 3d space (i.e. watching it grow over time). Not really sure what else you can do here.

Comment: the idea is to embed the above code in more than 3d. So if one wants to embed the above in a higher dimension, say 100 dimension, you just need to zero out the 4th up to 100th coordinates. So how can one achieve this?